# Using a filter to limit a GenericForeignKey model list with django-polymorphic

Tags: python, django, polymorphism, django-contenttypes

I have a number of Django models which inherit from PolymorphicModel (from django-polymorphic). I want to create a GenericForeignKey relation for a specific model type and it's child models.

Something like:

```
# application_one/models.py

from django.db import models
from polymorphic import PolymorphicModel
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

class ModelA(PolymorphicModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class ModelB(ModelA):
    new_property = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class ModelC(ModelA):
    other_property = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class OtherModel(models.Model):
    pass

class ModelWithRelation(models.Model):
     # We want to limit the related_model to ModelA, or it's children
     related_model = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
     object_id = models.IntegerField()
     content_object = GenericForeignKey('related_model', 'object_id')
```

--- and ---

```
# application_two/models.py
from application_one.models import ModelA

class ModelD(ModelA):
     pass
```

You can limit a the choice of the ContentType by explicitly specifying the model names in `limit_choices_to` but I actually want this to be a dynamic query for children of ModelA, because in our application we are expecting children of ModelA to exist in other Applications, and don't want to have to define them in application_one.

How would I go about defining a Q object (or whatever I need to do) to be able to set limit_choices_to on the related object (i.e. `related_model = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)`).

TIA!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a built-in feature of Django Polymorphic, you don't need to create a `GenericForeignKey`, just create a regular `ForeinKey` to `ModelA` and Django Polymorphic will take care of the rest.

See [Django Polymorphic's documentation on ForeignKeys](https://django-polymorphic.readthedocs.org/en/latest/advanced.html#manytomanyfield-foreignkey-onetoonefield) for more info

Comment: Fantastic! I should have known that!